# Jw Player not showing up at all

Tags: jquery, html, css, jwplayer, jwplayer7

Hi i am having a problem my JW Player is not showing up in my browser i tried other browsers and it still does not show up, there is a `<div>` that wraps it so i set a width and height to that div and it still does not show up, i also tried moving the video player and it still did not show up.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="videoplayerwrap">

                    <div id="se_video"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//embed.scaleengine.net/user/barakyah-channel/7.x/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="Z20sg3$ggS5FsdfDFGdR3tuktyDk5ne4vuRLfk50g=32="</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('#se_video').setup({
        autostart: 'false',
        sources: [
                        { file: 'rtmp://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/mp4:kollosal'},
            { file: 'http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/kollosal/playlist.m3u8'}
        ],
        rtmp: {
            'bufferlength': '5'
        },
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        androidhls: "true",
        primary: "flash"
    });
</script>
                </div>
```

css

```
.videoplayerwrap {
    float: left;
    width: 808px;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen an url end like this...`./mp4:kollosal` I tried Googling it using `inurl:mp4:kollosal` and didn't find even an AD.

Comment: man get educated thats a rtmp url @zer00ne

Comment: I know it is, yet I've never noticed an url formed as such. How or where do I find info on this type of url?

Comment: its from a system i have i upload the videos they give me live streaming and the URLS @zer00ne

Comment: Remove the hash(#) from the front of the ID you are passing into the JW player .setup(). It's not JQuery!

Comment: it does not work @jherrieven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `#` before setup element

```
jwplayer('#se_video') -> jwplayer('se_video')
```

Comment: but that was one of the problems

Comment: That was THE problem for why the player was not showing up. Your next issue is related to the fact you are using an invalid JW Player key. You need to include a proper, well formed JW Player key when trying to render a JW7 player.